# delayed execution and computation expression

Tags: f#

consider this code

```
let foo x = 
   seq {
      printfn $"1{x}"
      1
   }

let bar = foo 1
```

if i run this code then nothing is printed to the console UNTIL, I interpret the expression by evaluating the values in the sequence.

If I then have this

```
let program1 (x: int) = 
   IOProgram.programBuilder {
      printfn "start"
      do! print $"the number is {x}"
      return x.ToString()
   }

let execution = program1 1
```

then "start" is written to the console before i actually interpret the expression.

my 1st attempt to solve it was to add the Delay method in this computational expression (a free monad):

```
   type IOProgramBuilder () =
      member this.Bind (x, f) = bind f x
      member this.Return x = Pure x
      member this.ReturnFrom x = x
      member this.Zero () = Pure ()
      member this.Delay (f : Unit -> 'a) = f

   let programBuilder = IOProgramBuilder ()
```

But this changes the type of the returned CE to

```
Unit -> IOProgram<'a>
```

I COULD simply pass this around my program and only call it inside my interpreter, but that seems clunky. This isnt how seq is handled, if I create a `seq<'a>` I get `seq<'a>`, not `Unit -> seq<'a>`

I then added run

```
   type IOProgramBuilder () =
      ...
      member this.Run (f) = f()
```

but this simply undoes delay.

The answer maybe this
[computation-expressions-builder-part5](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-builder-part5/)

which seems to advocate wrapping the "inner type" inside a `unit -> 'a` (or Lazy<'a>).

Is this the answer? (is there a way to do this without the somersaults? If not I'll knock it up and post it as an answer.).

(apologies to Fyodor, he did answer the original vague question, I could have marked it as the answer and added a subsequent one, but its probably best to cover the whole thing in 1 go, I'll upvote it)

**Response to response (fyodor)**

consider

```
let foo x = 
   seq {
      printfn $"!{x}"
      1
   }

let bar = (foo 1).GetEnumerator()
```

If I were to wrap the my CE delay in a datatype to simulate (by analogy) the behaviour of seq, then it should behave like the above? and nothing would be printed to the console when I call GetEnumerator?

But that isnt what happens for my program, I run the 'delay' (i.e. GetEnumerator) method and it will immediately print "start" to the console, which isnt what Enumerable does.

Does seq delay the creation of the enumerator AND delay each bind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. In fact, you overshot a little.

When you define a `Delay` method, the compiler will insert a call to it, with the whole computation expression passed as a parameter, but inside a `unit -> 'a` function. So, if without `Delay` you had:

```
let program = ce { ... }
```

Then defining a `Delay` method will turn it into:

```
let program = ce.Delay( fun () -> ce { ... } )
```

Which is exactly what you need: if your `Delay` is just identity, then the ultimate result of the whole thing would be a function taking `Unit`, which, when called, will execute your whole CE.

**Your mistake** was also defining `Run`. When you define the `Run` method, the whole computation expression gets wrapped in it too:

```
let program = ce.Run( ce.Delay( fun() -> ce { ... } ) )
```

So it effectively "undoes" the effect of `Delay`.

Why such silly back and forth, you may ask? This is because `Delay` is not normally used just for "delaying" the execution. Its actual purpose is to facilitate things like `TryWith` or `Combine`, where there are multiple branches of the CE, and some of them should be executed or not, depending on reasons. This is when the compiler will insert `Delay` to prevent such branches from executing immediately. But then, at the very end, once everything is unfolded, you'd still want to return the "normal" result, not "delayed" one, - and this is where `Run` is inserted to "unwrap" the delayed computation.

### Response to comment

In your comment you state that this works, but it changes the expression's return type to a function, which is something you don't want. And why should you - `seq<'a>` is not a function, right?

But actually - yes, yes it is! It's a bit of an oversimplification, but for the purposes of this exercise you can think of `seq<'a>` as a function `unit -> list<'a>`. Every time you call the function, a fresh new list is generated, and all side-effects during its generation are executed. And this is not inherent to computation expressions either, it's a property of sequences specifically. Works regardless of how the sequence is constructed.

Try this:

```
let s = Seq.singleton 42 |> Seq.map (fun x -> printfn $"1{x}"; x * 2)

let a = Seq.head s    // prints "142"
let b = Seq.length s  // prints "142" again
```

Why doesn't it *look* like a function, you may ask? Because it's only *logically* a function, not literally. Literally it's an interface `IEnumerable<'a>` with a single member `GetEnumerator : unit -> IEnumerator<'a>` - and that's your function. It's just wrapped inside an interface, so you don't see it.

And you can totally wrap your values too. You can wrap the function inside a type constructor:

```
type DelayedProgram = DelayedProgram of (unit -> IOProgram)

member this.Delay f = DelayedProgram f
```

Or you can wrap it in an interface, like `seq` does:

```
type IDelayedProgram = 
  abstract member Run : unit -> IOProgram

this.Delay f = { new IDelayedProgram with member _.Run() = f() }
```

Or you can wrap it in `Lazy` - that way it's only initialized once on first access, but not every time, like `seq` does:

```
this.Delay f = Lazy.Create f
```

Or you can just make it a type alias and be done with it:

```
type DelayedProgram = unit -> IOProgram

this.Delay f = f
```

But you can't have it both ways: have it be not a function *and* have it delay-executed.

F# is not Haskell. It doesn't have the concept of "unevaluated thunk" - a value that's not there until you need it. In F#, if you have a value, it means whatever code generated it has been fully executed.

Comment: ah....well i overshot because i put delay in, BUT that doesnt actually solve the issue it just changes the type of what the builder returns to Unit -> CE.....let me update the question. Sorry...this is a very good answer

Comment: see updated question (again apologies), do I need to wrap my inner type/data as per https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-builder-part5/?
feel free to add this to you answer if that is indeed the best option, and I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: Added a response.

Comment: did u see https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-builder-part5/? it seems to do exactly what i want, the 'function' is inside the CE not outside, IEnumerable wraps 'unit -> IEnumerator<'a>' so the function is absorbed inside the datatype and you see seq<a>. I'll give it a go.

Comment: errr...actually maybe I'll try using Delay as you have done above

Comment: That post goes a whole different way: every single bind is delayed, not the whole thing. I actually wrote a whole answer how to do that at first, but then realized you were asking to copy what `seq` does, and threw it away.

Comment: hmmmm....its hurting my head a bit.....but I'm not too sure you are quite right about seq, let me add to the question, just to illustrate.

Comment: Well yes, of course it's all oversimplified, it would take way more time that I don't have to explain everything fully. Yes, seq kind of delays every bind, but not really. It's more complicated than that. And seq is not even a computation expressions to begin with, if you must know, it just looks like one, but in reality it's special syntax that the compiler handles in a special way.

Comment: ok, I'll try to delay each bind and see where that takes me (I know seq isnt a true CE, but it should be possible to write it AS a CE, and get the same behaviour, in which case I think it delays execution AND delays bind

Comment: I've written it and got nowhere...actually quite obviously (though my construction isnt quite as presented)...can i presume then that in fact it isnt possible to construct something like seq<> in a CE? the CE will inherently 'run' the initial code? (as demonstrated in my seq example)

Comment: No, you absolutely can. The result needs to be a function - wrapped or not, but a function - and then its execution will be delayed until you call the function.